# listView BackgroundColor

Tags: java, android

i have listView, each item have different BackgroundColor set in getView function:

```
if ((position % 2) == 0) {
    row.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(227, 227, 227));
} else {
    row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

and when click any item change BackgroundColor, set this code in onItemClick function:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(color.pressedColor);
```

but when i return to listView by click back button the item which was click don't return to normal BackgroundColor, it color stay same pressed BackgroundColor.

how can return the default BackgroundColor when press back button?

Answer (score 1):

You could save the current color to a temporary variable before re-coloring it. Then have your 'back' button change it back to whatever value the temporary variable holds. This will work for a single colour change roll back without any major coding ventures.

Comment: i save the backgroundColor in temporary variable, when i pressed on item in list view will change backgroundColor to pressed backgroundColor and will trans me to new activity, when i press back button how can return backgroundColor to normal backgroundColor?